# Is IIS blocking calls to cuda from my web app?

Tags: iis, cuda

I have an asp.net mvc 4 x64 web app that in the background does some calculations and returns some numbers to be rendered in the browser. All works fine in visual studio but when called from the project folder from the browser via IIS I get a CudaErrorNoDevice. This is error number 38 and so it does look like it's referencing all the external cuda dlls correctly, making the call and returning the error.

For testing I'm using the GetDeviceProperties() method.

I even plugged the Gpu into the displays just in case the browser got confused that the cuda call was for graphics. No luck though.

Can anyone confirm that calling the Gpu from a web app is a perfectly do-able thing to do? And if so, is there any specific configuration needed in IIS for Gpu's.

Thanks

IIS 8 Express, VS2012, Cuda 5.0, Gtx Titan (This is a 2nd Gpu, Gtx 660 is for display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that IIS is running at a service level that does not have access to the GPU (which is a WDDM device in this scenario.)

The usual suggestion would be to switch the GPU device to be in TCC mode (possible with most Quadro and Tesla GPUs), but that is not possible with a GeForce GPU (both of yours are GeForce GPUs).

As an alternative workaround, you may wish to try the method described [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/408076/running-cuda-in-a-service-example-of-a-cuda-service-in-vista-server-2008-and-windows-7/).

The statement about TCC support is a general one.  Not all Quadro GPUs are supported.  The final determinant of support for TCC (or not) on a particular GPU is the `nvidia-smi` tool.  Nothing here should be construed as a guarantee of support for TCC on your particular GPU.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this well known TTC feature.